# Is there a way to change the reporting period to quarter rather than the last 30 days on the usage of our website?

Tags: reports

Is there a way to change the reporting period to quarter rather than the last 30 days on the usage of our website?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OOTB reports in WSS\MOSS are not configurable.  You would need to create or buy a separate reporting solution.

Comment: mmmm, that's what I was thinking. Do you know of any tool?

Comment: Nintex has Nintex Reporting 2008 and Nintex Analytics 2010, I think @Muhimbi has worked on an analytics tool, http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put in custom time periods.  That would allow you use quarters instead.